# Interface inherits other interfaces not Classes?

Tags: java, inheritance

Interfaces are meant to be extended by classes and they can extend other interfaces

```
interface i1 {
    void in();
}

interface i3 {
}

class A implements i1, i3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }

    public void in() {
    }
}

class B {
}
```

What if we need to extend a Class for an interface?? It is not allowed why?

```
 interface i2 extends B; //incorrect
 class B implements i2; //correct
```

Comment: Stativ? whoa what is that

Comment: Because it doesn't make any sense for an interface to extend a class.  An interface is, well, an interface.  A class contains method definitions.

Comment: Interfaces cannot contain implementations, by design... instead of having an interface extend a class, why not use an abstract class (if it makes sense for your situation)?

Comment: @mc10 I think that will be added in java 8

Comment: @MightyPork It's been in Java for quite some time already... I don't understand the comment about Java 8.

Comment: the default implementation of an interface method has been there for a while? C'mon, since when, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, interfaces, unlike classes, have no implementation.

If an interface were to extend a class, it would then have that class's implementation.

The reason for interfaces not having implementation is that then classes/interfaces can "inherit" any number of them without the problems caused by multiple inheritance (a la C++).

Comment: Exactly and +1 for the last two lines, I hear this reason several times, but no one really tells what problem? Could you please tell more about the issues that the c++ inheritance creates?